# How to check for exact value in an includes() javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm checking a string that is delimited with pipes to populate checkboxes. I'm using the includes() to achieve this. But the problem is when two items are similar in names, they are both true because they both include the same string, event though they are different.

For example, in the string `language: "English|Non-English"`, and this state

```
const [state, setState] = useState({    
    language: "English|Non-English",
})
```

mapping the

```
{language.map((item) => {
   const checkboxvalues = state.language 
   return (
      <Grid key={item} item sm={4} md={3}>
         <FormControlLabel
            className={classes.switchcontrol}
            control={
               <Checkbox 
                  size="small" 
                  name={item} 
                  value={item} 
                  checked={checkboxvalues.includes(item)} 
                  onChange={handleOnChange} 
                />
             }
             label={item}
          />
       </Grid>
   );
})}

checked={checkboxvalues.includes(item)} //This makes English true for both
```

How can I make it so that it treats English and Non-English independently. Also, I have a similar case with "Name|First Name", so it's not just a dash, white space too

Thanks

Comment: What about using an array instead? `["English", "Non-English"]`

Comment: Ideally that would be great, but it's not my call. I get what I get in the API

Comment: Converting the string to an array shouldn't be too difficult provided the delimiter is always `|`. `"English|Non-English".split('|')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `checkboxvalues`, ideally outside the `map` call to avoid doing it for each checkbox:

```js
const checkboxvalues = state.language.split('|')
```

The rest of your code doesn't need to be changed because [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) also exists on arrays:

```js
checkboxvalues.includes(item)
```